# Azure AD B2C multiple application in one domain

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-page-application

I'm going to implement a multi-page React application in the same domain:

- domain.com/app1 - application 1 base path, /app1/index.html
- domain.com/app2 - application 1 base path, /app2/index.html

The user can access each app or both with a single login.

1. If user goes to `/app1`, he will be asked to login (in Azure AD B2C)
2. After logging in, he will be redirected back to `app1`

   1. If he doesn't have permission to access `app1`, show 404
   2. Or else, he can work with `app1`
   3. If he also has permission to access `app2`, he can go to `app2` anytime without asking to login (or silent log in could work either)

What I'm going to do is attach the app's permissions in MSAL `access_token`, using Custom Policy with Restful Technical Profile. So, when the user goes to an app, the app reads access_token and decides if the user permission has permission or not.

I'm asking if there's a proper or better way to do as requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah this should work well! Maybe don't use a 404 though. I would explain why the user doesn't have access so they can request it if needed.